# Algorithm which efficiently cycles through an array for matching elements based on constraints

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matching

I am doing a project and I've just now gotten around to optimizing. I was wondering if the community may be able to help.

I have a single array and my goal is to efficiently iterate through the array, taking out elements if they happen to match. (Matching is based on whether or not the function I have created to match them returns true)

My initial thought was to have a nested loop inside a main loop, but I very much want to stray from the O(n^2).

Thanks in advance.

**Edit** Sorry about that, the matching case is a checking of two Boolean values, two integers, and a double. I forgot to mention that earlier.

Comment: If we have no knowledge about the relation expressed by the function, then you can't do better than O(n^2) -- since there's no possible way to know ahead of time whether a given pair will match or not.  If OTOH there is some structure (e.g. transitivity, i.e. if A matches B and B matches C then A must match C) then it might be possible to go faster.

Comment: You should study the matching function.  Perhaps you can sort/segment your data into small groups that only match within themselves, thus in `O(n log(n))` time getting rid of most of the `O(n*n)` complexity?

Comment: Is this a O(1) check?  Why can't you iterate through an array and do a constant-time check on each element in O(_n_)?  Or are you comparing two elements against each other?  Are you just trying to remove duplicates?  It's unclear precisely what you mean by "matching elements."

Comment: It would be so much clearer if you share the matching function's code snippet.

Comment: "checking of two Boolean values, two integers, and a double" doesn't tell us anything useful I'm afraid.